# How to use cdkDropListEnterPredicate to check against multiple conditions?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material, angular-cdk

I have multiple draggable lists connected to multiple drop zones, but need to limit which items can be dragged based on variables already set within the app.  For example, if I have the following:

```
this.maxVirtuePts = 10;
this.reqSocialStatus = false;
this.allowedTheGift = true;
this.maxHermeticMajorVirtue = 1;
```

For maxVirtuePts, how do I limit the amount of items in the drop zone to 10?
For reqSocialStatus, how do I check that at least one item exists in a dropped zone?
For allowedTheGift, how do I check if the name of the dropped item contains specific text?
For maxHermeticMajorVirtue, how do I check if a dropped item from a specific list already exists to avoid adding additional items from the same origin list?

If anyone can suggest or provide examples of how to effectively use cdkDropListEnterPredicate, it would be much appreciated.

Added a StackBlitz:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-flpx5t

Answer (score 1):

In your drop function, you can check any condition you want if the condition not satisfied just call return this will stop the item from dropped into the zone

for example

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if(event.container.data.length>9){
     return // this will stop item from drop
    }
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Is it acceptable to have a whole range of if statements if I have multiple conditions to work with?  What is the use case between using normal if statements vs EnterPredicate?  In the final version of this view there may be close to 15-20 conditions at play.

Comment: @DuskChilder I don't know about the EnterPredicate function. So not sure about the difference. But because of EnterPredicate officially recommended I would suggest go with that.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using cdkDropListEnterPredicate, but only the final check that would block further items being transferred.  To get to the final check, I calculated the other conditions as variables.

Comment: Could you please provide an example?